# Define two sets in $\mathbb R^n$ by $A := \{(x,y) : y \geq e^x\}$ and $B := \{(x,y) : y = 0\}$. Prove that $A + B = \{(x,y) : y \geq 0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So I am trying to prove the above. The only information that i have is that

$A + B = \{a + b \in\mathbb R :a \in A, b \in B\}$

Any help with this proof would be great, I am just having a hard time getting started on it.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536294/define-two-sets-in-x-in-mathbbr2-by-a-x-y-y-%e2%89%a5-ex-and-b-x-y.

Comment: What you want to show is false. Note that if $(x,y)\in A$, then $y>0$. Thus, any $(a,b)\in A+B$ satisfies $b>0$.